# create aws log stream link dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

I have multiple aws batch jobs, which when fails, I print the name of the batch job for the end user, which they can use to search for the job in aws batch gui. From there they can get the aws cloudwatch logstream link to see more detailed logs.

How can I get that logstream link? And print it when the job fails along with name (this part is easy, once the logstream link is figured out)

When I looked at logstream link, I thought it can simply be created by concatenating string values, for example:

`https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=ap-south-1#logsV2:log-groups/log-group//aws/batch/job/log-events/batch-job-defn/default/1c2524f0b4b0432eb44bf36f2bacc887`

I have most of the information, except I can't figure out what's the last id (`1c2524f0b4b0432eb44bf36f2bacc887`)

Answer (score 0):

> By default, the streams are identified by the first 200 characters of
> the job name and the Amazon ECS task ID.

Source: [Using CloudWatch Logs with AWS Batch - AWS Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html)